# Error while using dupehammer

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, dupehammer, error-message

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35822583/1529630) as a duplicate. I have a dupehammer in both tags.

However, an error occurred:

[image]

I reloaded the page, and then it said I had voted to close, but the question was not closed because the dupehammer had not been used:

[image]

If the system detected an error while using the dupehammer, the close vote should have been rolled back. This way I would have been able to cast it again, using the dupehammer.

After that another user, who has no dupehammer, voted to close too. It seems the system detected my dupehammer and the question was closed, but my dupehammer is not shown in the close reason message:

[image]

Comment: It'd have been nice if you could have captured the error log console from the server.  That *may* have had more context clues into what was going on.

Comment: @Makoto The console doesn't show anything. The network devtool doesn't begin recording until opened, so once I saw the error it was too late.

Comment: Stuff appears to be timing out. In your case, the close vote was recorded, but the bit that's supposed to record the closure was terminated before completion.

Comment: It would be nice if the "*an error occured*" popup had a tooltip or info-icon that showed some details about the (nature of the) error.

Comment: Some details like "*an error occured - Blame Shog for this*"

Comment: Although it would have been useful to know it, the exact error that occurred is not the most important thing here, the real problem is the behavior of the system after the error: the OP should have been able to simply try again. Taking a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here's the deal. This is what the system was doing whenever a close vote was cast on a question:

1. Record the close vote
2. Retrieve all existing close votes from database
3. Check how many additional close votes are needed to close the question (will be zero for moderators and dupehammers)
4. If 3 is zero, close the question (this requires the list of close votes retrieved in 2)

When 2 or 4 fail (3 is a trivial step) the close vote is recorded but the question is not closed. Which is exactly what happened in this case.

I have changed it so that now the close vote is recorded immediately before closing the question. This was an easy change.

Now there is still the possibility that something fails after the vote is recorded and before the question is closed, but the odds of this happening are smaller than in the previous case, and completely preventing this would **not** be an easy change. So I'm going to leave it this way for now, if you are (or someone else is) still encountering this problem please report it.